# When install opencv on jetson nano, get -Wsuggest-override warning

Tags: opencv, warnings, nvidia-jetson, nvidia-jetson-nano

I use jetson nano developer kit 4 gb with default version ubuntu 18.04. When ı install openCV version 4.6.0:
firstly, ı do this steps,

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
$ sudo apt-get install nano
# install dphys-swapfile
$ sudo apt-get install dphys-swapfile
$ sudo nano /sbin/dphys-swapfile
# give the required memory size
$ sudo nano /etc/dphys-swapfile
# reboot afterwards
$ sudo reboot
```

then,

```
$ free -m
$ wget https://github.com/Qengineering/Install-OpenCV-Jetson-Nano/raw/main/OpenCV-4-6-0.sh
$ sudo chmod 755 ./OpenCV-4-6-0.sh
$ ./OpenCV-4-6-0.sh
```

This step takes 3 hours and when the filling process reaches 100%, I get the following error.

### TAKEN ERROR

```
In file included from home/opencv/build/modules/python_bindings_generator/pyopencv_generated_include.h:91:0,
                 from home/opencv/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:11:
home/opencv_contrib/modules/cudafeatures2d/include/opencv2/cudafeatures2d.hpp:121:26: warning: 'virtual void cv::cuda:DescriptorMatcher::clear()' can be marked override [-Wsuggest-override]
    CV_WRAP virtual void clear() = 0;
                         ^~~~~~~
home/opencv_contrib/modules/cudafeatures2d/include/opencv2/cudafeatures2d.hpp:121:26: warning: 'virtual void cv::cuda:DescriptorMatcher::empty() const' can be marked override [-Wsuggest-override]
    CV_WRAP virtual bool empty() const = 0;
                         ^~~~~~~
```

---

I formatted Jetson Nano again but it gave the same error.